# Get emails from Active Directory using declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap, jenkins-pipeline

Currently my workflow is using jenkins with multibranch-pipeline (declarative pipeline/jenkinsfile) to checkout from SVN, build, test with sonarqube and deploy to a weblogic server, it's working fine with all the branches needed.
Jenkins is configured to use active directory/ldap to enable all my colleagues to login with their credentials

I just don't know how to get all the emails from the users who did commit since the last build, as i want to send them an email (go and fix <3)

I'm kinda new to jenkins and i'm findind difficult to find some good documentation, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

With active directory enabled, jenkins already knows everything i need and i can just use this code inside the post{} section of the declarative pipeline

```
failure {
        script {
            def emails= []
            emails << emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']])
            emails = emails.join(',')
            emailext to: emails, subject:"JENKINS - ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName} - ${currentBuild.currentResult}", body: "Check out what you have done, jenkins is crying!!!"
        }
    }
```